# Finding the domain of an equation with two different inverse trigonometric functions.

Tags: calculus

I want to determine the domain of the equation below. When I solve the equation algebraically, I get that all the terms cancel out and the equation is defined for all x values. However, I know that the inverse of the trigonometric functions are defined within a certain intervall. For example arcus sine is defined for $|x|\leq 1$ and arcus tangent is defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. I also know that the function inside arctan is defined for $|x|\leq 1$. But how would I determine the domain of an equation with one inverse trig function at one side and another inverse trig function at the other side?
$$\arcsin(x) = 2\arctan\left(\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “domain of an equation”. If you mean “what are the $x$’s for which both sides are (independently) defined), then you’ve solved the problem on the left side ($|x|\leq 1$), and on the right you need to make sure you can do all the operations (which also require $|x|\leq 1$). But if you mean **solutions** (not domain), then that’s a different question altogether. **Functions** have domains. Equations don’t.

Comment: There are some nice relations between the arcus functions and the trigonometric functions of different kinds. For example $\tan(\arcsin x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ which can be derived by using the identities $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ and $\cos x = \sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}$ which could be helpful for your equation.

Comment: If you solve the equation then, like a mentioned in the post, all the terms will cancel out and the solutions will be $x\in\mathbb{R}$. The task is to determine all x, 'the domain', which satisfies the equation above. How would I combine the domain of the left hand side with the domain of the right hand side.

Comment: If you correctly solve the equation, then you will only get the $x$s for which the original equation is sensible. It is possible that you are taking some steps that are not as reversible or as correct as you think they are, but that is difficult to know without knowing exactly what it is you did to solve the equation. But that is not “domain”; that is **solution set** of the equation.

Comment: For example, if you took the equation $\sqrt{x}=-x$, squared both sides to get $x=x^2$, and then from here you got to $x^2-x=0$, hence $x(x-1) = 0$, hence $x=0$ or $x=1$, then the first step is not reversible (you can go from $\sqrt{x}=-x$ to $x=x^2$, but you can’t go from $x=x^2$ to $\sqrt{x}=-x$), which is why you get answers that are not really solutions to the original equation (namely, $x=1$ does not solve the original equation). You are likely doing something similar when solving, which means you are getting a superset of the solution set, rather than the solution set itself.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I solved the equation correctly and I assure you that the the terms cancel out. The solution is pretty straight forward. I take the $sin$ of both sides and then I set $arctan(p)=\theta$ to get the double angle of sine and then it's just plain algebra.

Comment: The first step is not even defined at all because the square root are not defined for negative numbers which means you would not be able to go either ways.

Comment: The first step is not fully reversible. That is, the function $f(x)=\sin(\arcsin(x))$ and the function $g(x)=x$ are not equal, because they don’t have the same domain. What you get is that $f(x)$ is equal to the function $h(x) = x,\quad -1\leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: If you are talking about my first step, going from $\sqrt{x}=-x$ to $x=x^2$, then you are incorrect. **If** $\sqrt{x}=-x$ holds, then certainly you conclude that $x=x^2$. You can definitely go in that direction.

Comment: (That is, you can go from $\sin(\arcsin(x))$ to $x$, but you cannot go from $x$ to $\sin(\arcsin(x))$ **unless** you know that $-1\leq x\leq 1$. So your steps are not fully reversible, which is how you are getting answers that satisfy your second equation but not your first)

Comment: But how does $\sqrt{x}=-x$ hold?  The square root of something is never a negative number. And lets say that the right hand side is positive, which it would be if x is negative, then the left hand side would not be defined.

Comment: The equation holds for $x=0$. What is the problem?

Comment: My “algebraic” solution works in the sense that at the conclusion of my argument I conclude that if $\sqrt{x}=-x$, then **either** $x=0$ or $x=1$. What I cannot conclude is that *if* $x=0$ or $x=1$, **then** $\sqrt{x}=-x$; the reason I cannot conclude that is that my chain of implications work only in one direction. Similarly, **your** chain of implications does not work in both directions. You can go from $\sin(\arcsin(x))$ to $x$, but you cannot go from $x$ to $\sin(\arcsin(x))$.

Comment: Hm, so you are saying that if I solve the equation in the correct way, I will get the solutions that satisfies the equation, in terms of specific x values?

Comment: I’m sahying that you need to be careful about the reversibility of your steps. We usually aren’t that careful because most steps we take are reversible (adding to both sides, subtracting from both sides, multiplying by nonzero constants, dividing by nonzero constants, etc). But in something like this, when the functions you are either cancelling or using to cancel have restricted domains, then you have to keep track of those restricted domains to make sure your steps are reversible. (Cont)

Comment: (Cont) When you go from one equation to another to another, you are technically just doing an implication going one way: if the first equation holds, then the second one holds. In many, **but not all** cases, the converse is also true: if the second equation holds, then the first one does as well. But here, when you are using $\arcsin(u)$ and the restricted $\sin$, they are reversible without additional hypothesis. (Cont)

Comment: Gotcha. Do you possibly have any other suggestions than taking the sin of both sides, to solve the equation?

Comment: Taking $\sin$ of both sides is fine... you just have to remember the information you otherwise lose in the process. When you take sine of both sides **and cancel the $\arcsin$ in the process**, you are “losing” the information that $-1\leq x\leq 1$. Keep track of it instead, by adding a “and $-1\leq x\leq 1$” clause to your assertion, and then it’s both correct and reversible. Then you just keep carrying the “and $-1\leq x\leq 1$” around.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that

- $\arcsin(x)$ is defined for $|x|\le 1$
- $\arctan(y)$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ then we need $1-x^2 \ge 0 \implies|x|\le 1$

then by $x=\sin u$ and $-\frac{\pi}2 \le u \le \frac{\pi}2$, such that $|x|\le 1$, we have

$$\arcsin(\sin u) = 2\arctan\left(\frac{\sin u}{1+\sqrt{1-\sin^2 u}}\right)$$

$$ u = 2\arctan\left(\frac{\sin u}{1+\cos u}\right)$$

$$ \frac u2 = \arctan\left(\frac{\sin u}{1+\cos u}\right)$$

$$ \tan \left(\frac u2\right) = \frac{\sin u}{1+\cos u}$$

which always holds, therefore the given equality holds for any $x$ such that $|x|\le 1$.

Comment: How do you get to your claim about the left hand side?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I've used $-1\le \arcsin x\le 1$...something wrong?

Comment: That tells you something about when the equation can be true, rather than tell you something about what you need for “the existence of the left hand side”. The left hand side by itself is sensible whenever $|x|\leq 1$. I understand the question itself is unclear, but then talking about LHS and RHS separately does not help clarify things.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for your kind suggestion. I try to revise that!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I've updated the discussion.

Comment: Your first step, going from $\arcsin(\sin(u))$ to $u$, requires $-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq u\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. Without that condition, it is incorrect.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes you are absolutely right! I fix that.